# How to define a variable that takes spaces of several other variables?

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, arm, win-universal-app

This code is written in MS ARM format. I need to define a variable called `psxRegs` which would take exactly the spaces of variables from `reg` to `intCycle` so that I can export it. However, I don't know how to achieve that. How can this be done?

```
    AREA    |.bss|,DATA,READWRITE,ALIGN=4

invc_ptr          SPACE 4
address           SPACE 4

;psxRegs
reg               SPACE 128
lo                SPACE 4
hi                SPACE 4
reg_cop0          SPACE 128
reg_cop2d         SPACE 128
reg_cop2c         SPACE 128
pcaddr            SPACE 4
                  SPACE 4
                  SPACE 4
                  SPACE 4
intCycle          SPACE 256

rcnts             SPACE 7*4*4
mem_rtab          SPACE 4
```

Comment: I am not familiar with this assembler, but usually you can just write `psxRegs:`. Note that these symbols don't normally have size information.

Comment: You should be able to type several lines each containing one label and no operands, they will all take the value of the current location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using an assembler, what you are thinking of as named variables are in fact only labels referring to memory locations.  What this means is that something like this has the effect described below:

```
psxRegs:
reg               SPACE 128
lo                SPACE 4
hi                SPACE 4
```

`reg`, `lo` and `hi` are being used to define named labels that can be used within your code to obtain the address (after assembly) of specific memory locations.  In a very similar way, `psxRegs:` defines a label but does not reserve memory. In fact, it is an alias for `reg` since no memory is reserved when it is defined.

This may have other implications in your case.  It's not clear if you are simply looking for an alias for `reg` or if you are trying to also reference `lo` and `hi`. You can access `lo` and `hi` by accessing `[psxRegs+128]` and `[psxRegs+132]` respectively.  However, this might be completely unnecessary since you can access those same values through `[reg+128]` and `[reg+132]`.

Please note that the `:` trailing `psxRegs` may or may not be required in your assembler.  I'd recommend that you try it *without* the colon first. If that fails to assemble, add the colon.

Comment: I think you're right. However, shouldn't it be [psxRegs+128] and [psxRegs+132] when accessing lo and hi? And yes, it should be psxRegs without no trailing for MS ARM assembler.